# How to change an array to list

Tags: arrays, typescript, list

I would like to make a function that changes an array and returns a list of Node in typescript. Assume the starting index is 0.
I am getting several errors with the code.

edited code:

```
export let arrayToList = (list: [number], index: number): Node<number> => {
    for (let i = list.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i === list.length) {
            return cons(null);
        } else {
            return cons(list[i]);
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: And those errors are...?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. "Not all code paths return a value"

Comment: Why do you need the for, by the way? It's pretty much just a return, so it's only ever gonna loop once (or zero times, if the array is empty, in which case execution falls off the function, hence why there's a code path without a return).

Comment: I wanted the returned list to be in the exact same order as the initial array. I figured I would have start it from the last index of the array to the first. (if that makes sense)

Comment: Doesn't explain why you need a for.